# Referencing Backbone views from app view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Hey all I am pretty new to Backbone though I have put several days into trying to get familiar with this framework, and it seems everytime I start feeling comfortable I run across a new problem.

I am wondering how to reference a view that is rendered from within my main appview. I know this is a really simple issue but I just can't seem to figure it out.

So for instance I have a simple view

```
    var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //something here including render function
});
```

Then I render that view from within the main app view

```
var myApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function{
        var mysubView = new SubView();
        mysubView.render();
    },
    editSomething: function{
        mysubView.remove();
    }
});
```

When I try and reference that view from a function (editSomething:) in the main app view, I get a reference error.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have two views that include forms. I want to swtich between the two forms as an edit function is called and when an add function is called. But I can't seem to access the views that have already been rendered.

I don't want to initialize and render a new view before removing the existing view because from what I understand, I will start to get a bunch of views floating in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference it using `this`:

```
var myApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function{
        this.subView = new SubView();
        this.subView.render();
    },
    editSomething: function{
        this.subView.remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have tried this solution but I still get: TypeError: Result of expression 'this.subView' [undefined] is not an object.

Comment: Could you update the original question with more complete code? The error is in how you register the events. I'd be happy to assist.

Comment: Never mind. Your answer was correct. I wasn't initializing the view with the this.subview = new SubView(); Once I did that it worked.